# Comparing 2 LBPs (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, textures, histogram, lbph-algorithm

I am using code from [bytefish.de](https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/tree/master/lbp)  to generate my LBPs. If I generate 2 LBPs and their corresponding histograms, what is the best way to compare them?

This is my code so far:

```
#include "lbp.hpp"
#include "histogram.hpp"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    //template image
    Mat temp = imread("Template.jpg",1);
    //image to be compared to
    Mat match = imread("Match.jpg",1);

    Mat dst,dst2; // image after preprocessing
    Mat lbp,lbp2; // lbp image
    Mat hist,hist2;

    //Convert to gray
    cvtColor(temp, dst, 6);
    cvtColor(match, dst2, 6);
    //remove noise
    GaussianBlur(dst, dst, Size(5,5), 5, 3, BORDER_CONSTANT);
    GaussianBlur(dst2, dst2, Size(5,5), 5, 3, BORDER_CONSTANT);
    //gets the lbp
    lbp::ELBP(dst,lbp,1,8);
    lbp::ELBP(dst2,lbp2,1,8);

   // normalize(lbp2, lbp2, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
    //normalize(lbp, lbp, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

    //get histograms
    lbp::histogram(lbp,hist,255);
    lbp::histogram(lbp2,hist2,255);

    //comparing the 2 LBP histograms
    double compareHist = cv::norm(hist-hist2);

    cout<<compareHist<<endl;

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically it gives me a quantifiable number as to how similar these two images are.
My question is, how do I improve this result? Whats a better way of acheiving a quantifiable number based on how similar 2 LBPs are?

Thanks.

Comment: it is assumed that the two images are always aligned correctly before generating lbp?

Comment: @basav Yes they are. Very subtle differences between orientation and alignment.

Comment: @Miki compareHist does not seem to work with the histograms I am producing. All give a high similarity rate.

Answer (score 1):

The LBP just gives you a (rather large) feature vector. To make anything useful of that you would typically process many example images (all belong to the class of images that you define as "being alike") and then use a Support Vector Machine to train a behavior that lets it recognize this likeness.

Just comparing two LPBs does normally not give you much information about the likeness of two images. To see that: Just translate the first image by one cell size of your LBP algorithm. The second LBP will then appear to be a shifted version of the first LBP. As you normally have no information as to how images are aligned or rotated it very difficult to compare two LBPs by some simple logic.

Comment: what if he makes sure that they are aligned and oriented correctly?just curious

Comment: Even if I do store, say, 10 templates of the same time of image, and apply LBP on all 10 images. What do I do next in order to compare it to a single image to Match with?

Comment: @basav: Then the LBPs should be very similar in a value-by-value comparison. But then also the images should be very similar in a pixel-by-pixel comparison.

Comment: @RK2015: You would typically many more than 10 images, and these images should show all the variations that a human viewer would just ignore (translation, rotation, scaling in a certain range ...). Then let a support vector machine gather your LBPs and build kind of clusters in an N-dimensional space (N being number of values in a single LBP). Finally you would take a test-image, compute its LBP and see if that falls into the neighborhood of any the N-dimensional clusters your SVM has found.